# How to use excel vba to find sheetname in the formula of all cells and replace with others?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to use excel vba to find sheetname in the formula of all cells within used range and replace the sheetname with another sheetname. The sheetname to be replaced new sheetname both are saved in a cell such as A1 and A2, respectively.

There are similar posts but just not the same.

Comment: Try starting by recording a macro using a single search/replace operation and selecting the lookin >> formulas option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use simple Excel `Search and Replace` routine?

1. Select the range you need to process.
2. Go `Home` Ribbon > `Find & Select` > `Replace...` or simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Fill in both fields with the respective sheet names, but **do not forget** leading and trailing `'` symbols in case sheet name has **spaces**.
4. Press `Replace All` and you're done.

In case you has no choice but VBA - follow @Tim W. advice and record the above steps with macro recorder. Good luck!

Comment: Great. I do not know that can find and replace what is inside a formula. Thanks...

Comment: @user19041 If you're happy with the solution - please tick it to accept the answer and mark the question solved. Thanks!